# Struggling with the Basics - Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am struggling with Perl to write a basic parser and thought I'd turn to you folks for some assistance.

The desired output is to filter through a large file as shown below and look for instances of 'License      : Unknown' and write the IP address and hostname of the devices with Unknown Licenses separated by a comma.

Expected Output:

```
10.132.215.292,BOL03273D
```

____DATA_____

```
spawn ssh -p 22 -c 3des -x -l bitops 10.132.215.292
bitops@10.132.215.292's password: 
register system.core2
BOL03273D # 
BOL03273D # terminal length 0
Unknown action 0
BOL03273D # terminal width 132
Unknown action 0
BOL03273D #  c v
ambiguous command before 'v'
Command fail. Return code 1
BOL03273D # edit root
Unknown action 0
BOL03273D # get webfilter status
Locale       : english
License      : Unknown
Expiration   : N/A
-=- Server List (Wed Dec 16 17:01:31 2015) -=-
IP                  Weight    RTT Flags  TZ    Packets  Curr Lost Total Lost
96.45.33.65             30    358        -8        127          0         49
209.222.147.36           0    427        -5        124          0         51
209.222.147.43           8    447        -5        130          0         57
64.26.151.36            16    468        -5        132          0         59
66.117.56.42            27    458        -5        135          0         62
66.117.56.37            45    497        -5        143          0         71
64.26.151.35            65    527        -5        143          0         70
69.195.205.102          91    507        -5        155          0         83
64.26.151.37           107    538        -5        157          0         85
96.45.33.64            128    397        -8        152          0         79
69.195.205.101         138    550        -5        164          0         92
62.209.40.74           141    627         1        160          0         89
208.91.112.196         158    417 D      -8        211          0        137
80.85.69.41            190    588         0        168          0         96
62.209.40.73           196    657         1        167          0         95
80.85.69.40            203    617         0        169          0         97
80.85.69.37            206    577         0        168          0         95
80.85.69.38            228    647         0        172          0         99
208.91.112.198         258    487 DI     -8        316          0        240
62.209.40.72           297    677         1        184          0        112
121.111.236.180        306    607         9        175          0        103
BOL03273D # 
BOL03273D #exit
Connection to 10.132.215.292 closed.
10.132.215.272
spawn ssh -p 22 -c 3des -x -l bitops 10.132.215.272
bitops@10.132.215.272's password: 
register system.core2
BOL00093D # 
BOL00093D # terminal length 0
Unknown action 0
BOL00093D # terminal width 132
Unknown action 0
BOL00093D #  c v
ambiguous command before 'v'
Command fail. Return code 1
BOL00093D # edit root
Unknown action 0
BOL00093D # get webfilter status
Locale       : english
License      : Contract
Expiration   : Fri Jun 26 19:00:00 2020
-=- Server List (Wed Dec 16 17:03:11 2015) -=-
IP                  Weight    RTT Flags  TZ    Packets  Curr Lost Total Lost
96.45.33.65             30     37        -8      28851          0        651
209.222.147.43           0     88        -5      16130          0        791
64.26.151.35             0    172        -5      15977          0        584
66.117.56.42             0     89        -5      16382          0       1065
66.117.56.37             0     89        -5      16382          0       1063
64.26.151.37             0    177        -5      15972          0        592
209.222.147.36           0     90        -5      16144          0        806
64.26.151.36             0    176        -5      15956          0        589
69.195.205.101           0    107        -5      16512          0       1150
69.195.205.102           0    107        -5      16470          0       1109
96.45.33.64             30     43        -8      27827          0        676
208.91.112.196          30     63 DI     -8      16687          0       1140
208.91.112.198          30    263 D      -8      17476          0       2089
80.85.69.38             50    167         0      15964          0        605
80.85.69.37             50    167         0      15961          0        602
80.85.69.41             50    168         0      15959          0        600
80.85.69.40             50    167         0      15980          0        621
62.209.40.73            60    198         1      16249          0        928
62.209.40.74            60    197         1      16278          0        959
62.209.40.72            60    197         1      16246          0        925
121.111.236.180        140    151         9      16147          0        786
121.111.236.179        140    160         9      16140          0        779
BOL00093D # 
BOL00093D #exit
Connection to 10.132.215.272 closed.
10.106.209.231
```

Current Code --

```
$infile='final.log';
$outfile='License_Unknown.txt';
open(INPUT, $infile);
@data = <INPUT>;
close(INPUT);
open(OUTPUT, ">$outfile");

$siteid="";
$licensestate="";
$mgmtip="";


for ($i=0; $i <= $#data; ++$i)
{
   if ($data[$i] =~ /hntools/)
   {
    @line=split(/@/,$data[0])
    @sameline=split(/'/,$data[0])
    $mgmtip=$sameline[1];
    print OUTPUT "\n$mgmtip,";
   }

   if (($line[i] =~ /License      : Unknown/))
   {
        $siteid=$line[0];
        print OUTPUT " $siteid, ";
    }
    chomp $line[2];

}


close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: We will need to see your Perl code before we can help with any problems you may be having. Or does *" thought I'd turn to you folks for some assistance"* mean *"please do my work for me"*?

Comment: Where does your expected output IP address `10.106.209.227` come from?

Comment: Edited above. Thanks.

Comment: Fair point! I have added my basic code

Answer (score 3):

OK, so your perl code could do with a bit of tidying up first:

- Put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` right at the top - it makes more errors, but they're the ones that'll bite you later.
- You don't actually need to iterate an array explicitly like that - you shouldn't bother unless you need to reuse your count, and just use `for (@array) {` instead.
- You can iterate by record, using `$/` to set a record seperator. It looks like you could use "Connection to".
- You can pattern match against all of your current record, and this does so by default.
- 3 arg file opens with lexical file handles are good. e.g. `open (my $output, '>', 'License_Unknown.txt' ) or die $!;`
- as is testing the return code of it.

So something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#set record seperator
local $/ = 'Connection to';

#read files from either STDIN or specified on command line (like grep/sed etc.)
while (<>) {

    #select the first IP-like from the block. (This regex could
    #be better, but works for your sample).
    my ($ip) = m/\w+\@(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'s password/;

    #match the license line, and extract the value
    my ($license)  = m/License\s+:\s+(\w+)/;
    my ($hostname) = m/(\w+)\s+#/;

    #print both.
    next unless defined $license;
    print "$ip,$hostname\n" if $license eq 'Unknown';
}
```

#### output

```
10.132.215.292,BOL03273D
```

`$/` is the input record seperator. Normally it's a linefeed - so perl iterates one line at a time. But you can set it to a number of bytes, or an alternative string - but not a regular expression. In a `while` loop perl reads it's input until it hits that point (or end of file) and then 'feeds' that chunk through to the loop. Which is why the above works - we loop twice, but then use patterns to pick out the bits of data we're interested in.

You can match against other elements - I grab the first IP address in a chunk, but specifically the line:

```
bitops@10.132.215.292's password:
```

YOu can match with:

```
m/bitops\@(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)'s password:/
```

Although note - that matches digit-dot-digit etc. but *won't* match if you've a hostname in there. (that contains letters).

So perhaps you'd want:

```
m/bitops\@([\w\.]+)'s password:/
```

The various elements in regex are summarised in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)  but it's quite a big topic - regular expressions are basically a programming language in their own right.

Comment: It's a good try, but the OP asked to *"write the IP address and hostname of the devices with `Unknown` Licenses"*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Borodin and truly appreciate you teaching while sharing some code Sobrique!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Borodin and truly appreciate you teaching while sharing some code Sobrique! Hope you guys don't mind follow up questions. 1) Where is $/ referenced again while looping? 2) What is the best place to learn regex? 3) How can I instead grab the IP addresses from the following line 'bitops@10.132.215.292's password:' 4) Similarly, how can traverse farther down and grab the Site ID from the following line 'BOL03273D # get webfilter status' given the license is Unknown.

Comment: @telecomToperl: **1)** $\ is referred to only once. It makes a sticky change to the string that Perl uses to delimit records in the file and needn't be accessed again. **2)** There are many on line resources; just google for `learn regex` **3)** Change `m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/` to `m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*password/` **4)** Sobrique's solution doesn't deal with the host name, so it's too big a change to put in a comment

Comment: Amended code. `$/` is set once to tell perl where to break up input. _usually_ it's `\n` (linefeed) to read line by line, but for data that is chunked setting it to something else is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution that uses state variables instead of changing the record separator to read a block at a time

It's hard to tell from such a short data sample exactly what landmarks can be used reliably for navigation. I've assumed that each block always starts with a line starting with `spawn` and ending with the host IP address, and that it ends with a line that starts with `Connection` and ends with `closed`. I'm also banking on the host names containing just capital letters and decimal digits. I'm pretty certain that I can rely on the format of the `License : Unknown` line

This program expects the path to the input file as a command-line parameter

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($ip, $host, $unknown);

while ( <> ) {

    if ( / (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) .+ password /x ) {
        $ip = $1;
    }
    elsif ( / ^ ([A-Z0-9]+) \s+ # /x ) {
        $host //= $1;
    }
    elsif ( / ^ License \s+ : \s+ Unknown /x ) {
        $unknown = 1;
    }
    elsif ( / ^ Connection .+ closed /x ) {

        if ( $ip and $host and $unknown ) {
            print "$ip,$host\n";
        }

        ($ip, $host, $unknown) = (); # reset state variables
    }
}
```

#### output

10.132.215.292,BOL03273D

Comment: Thank You! Would love to get to a place where I can spin up something like this myself. What is happening when you are setting "$ip=$1" and "$host //= $1;?" Also, would love to hear of your favorite resources for practicing Perl? I'd need it for similar parsing jobs

Comment: `$1` is the first capture from the regular expression (the bit in brackets). `//=` is 'assign-if-undefined'. So a good way of giving a 'default' in case there's something not present. (In your sample - you have an IP right at the end, which _might_ be the start of an incomplete record).

Comment: Best resource for practicing perl: Stack Overflow. Answer questions. It's a great way to learn and refine code.